# How do I check if a bytes32 variable in a mapping has been assigned value?

Tags: solidity, mapping, bytes32

For example, for:

```
mapping(address => bytes32) public addressName;
```

which one of the following syntax is correct?

```
address _address = 0x...; //an actual address
require(addressName[_address]!="");
require(addressName[_address]!=0);
require(addressName[_address]!=null);
require(addressName[_address]!=bytes32(""));
require(addressName[_address]!=bytes32(0));
```

Comment: One way to check it by yourself is to use http://remix.ethereum.org

Answer (score 6):

In Solidity mappings, *all* possible keys are assigned 0 by default.

So if a valid value in your use case is always non-zero, then you can check with:

```
addressName[addr] != 0
```

And if 0 is a valid value, then by definition it's already been initialized to that at the beginning.

Comment: When I check a new key, the value of addressName[new_key] is "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000". Does it have the same value of 0?

Comment: @Daniel, yes, it's the same.

Answer (score 3):

`addressName[address]!=0` will work to check if the address has been assigned a value. this assumes that 0 is not a valid/possible assignment in your application.

```
 function test(address addr, bytes32 email) public {
        require(addressName[addr] == 0); // if 0 then no assignment has taken place, if 1 the address has been registered (reverse)
        addressName[address] = email;  // map the address to the email
    }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

`address` is a reserved keyword (a type), so `addressName[address]` is not even going to compile.

If we replace it with `name`, for the sake of this answer, then you can try something like this:

```
bytes(addressName[name]).length > 0
```

Comment: @Briomkez: Well, I admit that I haven't even tried to implement and compile a function which refers to `addressName[address]`, so I might be wrong. But can you please provide an example of such function? It should be something like `function func(address address) external view returns (bool)`, which if to be honest, I still can't see how it would compile (and it would be a very confusing prototype even if it does compile somehow).

Comment: I cancelled the comment because I read the answer wrongly. Sorry

Comment: @goodvibration Reserved keywords are, in pretty much every language, only relevant when that's the full name. If the variable was named `address`, `uint`, or even `function`, those wouldn't work, but `addressName` is valid.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, the "address" in "addressName[address]" represents an actual address.

Comment: @goodvibration When I try bytes32(addressName[name]).length > 0 where name is a new address which hasn't been assigned value, it returns true.

Comment: @flygoing: I did not understand anything of what you you wrote, or how it is related to my answer (which you should probably read again). Anyway, in the expression `addressName[address]`, the usage of the keyword `address` as a variable name (in this case, a key to the `addressName` map) should lead to a compilation error.